# Why does the macos bigsur theme installed after Ubuntu 20.04 download the update no longer work?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, themes

[image: Google Chrome]
[image: Mozilla Firefox]
[image: Visual Studio Code]
[image: Terminal]

As shown in the image, the four corners of the original window should be rounded, but after installing the update, the bottom two corners became right angles. The applications that this happens include Visual Studio Code, Google Chrome, Mozilla Firefox, Terminal, etc.

(I installed the Mac Os Big Sur theme. It worked fine before I installed the update.)